# Can you replace a number with a String in a MySQL result set?

Tags: mysql

I'm curious as to if it's possible to display a line of text instead of the actual result returned through MySQL, for example I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( 
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    gender SMALLINT(1)
);
```

Now, I want to execute the following Query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

This would by default return something like this (Dummy data):

```
   id  |     name    | gender
  ---------------------------
    1        Rob         0
    2        Sam         1
    3       Alyssa       1
    4        Tom         0
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to change it so instead of outputting `0/1` it will output like so:

```
id  |     name    | gender
  ---------------------------
    1        Rob     male
    2        Sam     female
    3       Alyssa   female
    4        Tom     male
```

Comment: @e4c5 - I marked it correct, sorry about that. When the timer stops me from marking I tend to forget.

Comment: no worries. All the best with your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [CASE WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

```
SELECT id, name, CASE gender WHEN 0 THEN 'male' ELSE 'female' END FROM users.
```

CASE WHEN is part of mysql's flow control statements. Generally when even you might want to select something based on a comparision you do a `CASE WHEN comparision THEN valule ELSE some other value END`. Mysql also has an IF ELSE but this is used in stored procedures rather than simple queries.

Comment: thanks @VicenteOlivertRiera, the perils of the fastest gun inthe west game

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       CASE gender WHEN 0 THEN 'male' WHEN 1 THEN 'female' END AS gender
FROM   users
```

Answer (score 2):

use `case` ... `when` ... `then` ...`else`

```
select id, Name, case gender when 1 THEN 'female' else 'male' end as gender from users
```

Answer (score 0):

For Replacement of content or datat,You have to use "Case When Status"
[Case When Stateement In MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html),

By Using this You can perform your result as per your need.